# Rendering partial from js.erb template produces content with html tags' remnants

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem with rendering `@results` from `show.js.erb`. Output looks like:[image: output from show.js.erb template]

**show.js.erb**

```
$('#results').empty();
$('#results').html("<ul><%= escape_javascript(render(@results)).html_safe %></ul>");
```

**_result.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <%= link_to(result.title, result.uri) %><br>
  <span class="urls"><%= result.uri %></span>
</li>
```

Using `_result.html.erb` in `show.html.erb`:

```
<ul>
  <%= render @results %>
</ul>
```

produces correct output.

The suspected culprit is `<%= escape_javascript(render(@results)).html_safe %>`.
I've tried `<%= raw(escape_javascript(render@results)) %>` but with no luck.
App is created with Rails 3.0.8.

**Edit 1:**

Longer version of **show.js.erb**:

```
$('#results').empty();
$('#results').html("<ul><%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "results/result",   :collection => @results)).html_safe %></ul>");
```

output stays the same as on the image with `a>`, `li>` and whatnot.

**Edit 2:**

HTML rendered by `show.js.erb`:
[image]

**Edit 3:**

```
<a href="http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial">Rake Tutorial | Jason Seifera&gt;<br>  <span class="urls">http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorialspan&gt;li&gt;</span></a>
```

**Edit 4:**

without `html_safe`:

```
$('#results').empty();
$('#results').html('<ul><%= escape_javascript render(@results) %></ul>');
```

Output:

[image: output without html_safe]

The `</` are already eaten by `escape_javascript`.

**Edit 5: It is working! Finally!**

```
$('#results').html('<%= escape_javascript("<ul>#{render(@results)}</ul>").html_safe %>');
```

It is Dogbert's answer with `.html('')` quotes and `.html_safe`.

Comment: Can you post the raw html output? Firebug tends to clean up invalid tags.

Comment: I've updated question (Edit 3) with html output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try using this for your js.erb

```
$('#results').html(<%= escape_javascript "<ul>#{render(@results)}</ul>"%>);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I added `.html('')` quotas. And when I was looking at raw html output, I've noticed it is correct! I've added `.html_safe` at the end and everything is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Two idea here:

1. Missing a ; after empty()

   ```
   $('#results').empty();
   ```
2. I've had trouble with using short-hand renders but the long version always works.

   ```
   $('#results').html("<ul><%= escape_javascript(render( :partial => "results/result", :collection => @results)).html_safe %></ul>");
   ```

## Next try

Change the double quotes to single quotes on the `.html('')`

Comment: Thanks for an answer. `;` is there but I lost it in typing question. I've tried long version but without `_` (it was giving missing partial error), sadly output is the same like in short version.

Comment: I don't think you've said what the output is.  Can you?  I might help.

Comment: Like on the image. Links are working. But title of the link has `a>` appended at the end. In span containing uri `span>li>` are appended. The same partial used in `show.html.erb` produces correct results.

Comment: can you try to change the double quotes to single quotes on the .html('')

Comment: I've updated question with HTML output. `</` are missing and `>` is transformed in HTML entity.

Comment: can you try $('#results').html('<ul><%= escape_javascript render(@results) %></ul>');

Comment: It outputs html source as text.

Comment: right but is it correct.  I am trying to eliminate that the .html() is somehow the problem.  Would it work better by going with .append() and creating the jQuery object separately.

Comment: In Edit 4 I've added output without `html_safe` and `</` are eaten. I've tried `.append()` and the output stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1553
Try this with Rails 3.0.7?

Comment: Yes, that's it. `</` are missing. Dogbert has workaround for this.